# Perl - Template Toolkit - How get list of variables in the template?

Tags: perl, templates, dancer

I am using Perl with [`Dancer`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer) and [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit).

I'm trying to create a generic routine that will be passed a template and the HTTP GET/POST parameters.

I need to find a way to get a list of the variables in the template, so I can retrieve them from the parameters, or return an error if one or more are missing.

I can go an ugly regex route, but I was hoping for a better/cleaner way.

All the templates are XML/SOAP with a few variables here and there.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Template::Plugin::Stash](http://p3rl.org/Template::Plugin::Stash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you enable the `TRACE_VARS` option on the template context then you can use the `variables` method to get a hash of all the values accessed.

This code shows a brief example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Template::Context;
use Data::Dump;

my $template = '[% person.name %] <[% person.email %]>';

my $context = Template::Context->new(TRACE_VARS => 1);
my $compiled = $context->template(\$template) or die $context->error;
my $variables = $compiled->variables;

dd $variables;
```

**output**

```
{ person => { email => {}, name => {} } }
```

Comment: Where did this come from?  I see no reference to TRACE_VARS or variables() in the documentation for Template::Context.  But it does work.  ???

Comment: @DouglasMauch: The `template` method from `Template::Context` returns a `Template::Document` object, so it's in the [documentation for `Template::Document`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Document). I used `Template::Context` so that I could set `TRACE_VARS`.